# Update Spreadsheets with data from Google BigQuery does not work

Tags: google-bigquery

I followed the instruction at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bigquery_tutorial to populate a Spreadsheet with BigQuery data. I followed the steps but when I run the BigQuery -> Run Query in the spreadsheet, I get the error "Exception: Required parameter is missing".

I used the exact same piece of code in example with the following line changed to:
var projectNumber = '770233629555';

Could anyone please assist?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the red bar at the top of the doc that says:
"Please note that some of the methods below have incorrect parameters listed. See [this](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/11/code-updates-required-for-apps-script.html) blog post for the required changes."

For instance, you'll want to change the BigQuery.query line to:

```
var resource = {
  query: query,
  timeoutMs: 1000
};
result = BigQuery.Jobs.query(resource, projectId);
```

Also, check out the full AppsScript example [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch12/query.gs).

Comment: I tried the full AppsScript example as it is [link](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch12/query.gs) but I got the error: Encountered " <INTEGER_LITERAL> "770233629555 "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF> . I have put the error screenshots at [screen1](http://goo.gl/qfahgg) and [screen2](http://goo.gl/nVl1fs)

Comment: So that looks like what I would expect if you selected the wrong menu item... that error would come from running a query where the query text was the project id.

Comment: I did not change a single word in the sample code at the [link](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch12/query.gs) . It does not work even when I replace the line: var PROJECT_ID_PROPERTY = 'PROJECT_ID' by the line var PROJECT_ID_PROPERTY = '770233629555' .

Comment: Could anyone please suggest me with a sample code that will let me query a BigQuery table and output to the excel file?

Comment: The code I linked to does work. You just need to run the 'Set Project' menu item once, then replace select some text that you want to run as your query and run the 'Run a query' menu item. The error you showed was what happens when you try to run a query but the query text is just the project id.

Comment: Hi, if you have some troubles querying BQ from Google Sheets — just try our [add-on](http://goo.gl/9IqjgK). I bet you'll enjoy it.